# Problemas ao ajustar um modelo de efeitos mistos utilizando o pacote gamlss

Tags: banco-de-dados, r, modelagem, regressão, ciência-de-dados

Estou tentando ajustar um modelo de efeitos mistos considerando o pacote `gamlss`.

O modelo que eu estou ajustando é definido a seguir:

```
library(gamlss)
ModelGamlss <- gamlss(log(Var1)~re(fixed=~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
(Var4)+(Var5),random = list(Var6=pdDiag(~Var7))),
data=Data2)
```

No entanto, o seguinte erro é apresentado:

```
Error in gamlss(log(Var1) ~ re(fixed = ~log(Var1)~re(fixed=~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+(Var4)+ : 
  The data contains NA's, use data = na.omit(mydata)
```

Após me deparar com este erro, realizei a seguinte modificação na sintaxe do modelo considerado:

```
ModelGamlss <- gamlss(log(Var1)~re(fixed=~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
(Var4)+(Var5),random = list(Var6=pdDiag(~Var7))),
data=na.omit(Data2))
```

Todavia, um novo erro é apresentado:

```
Error in lm.wfit(x, z, w, method = "qr", ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases
```

Como poderia solucionar os problemas enfrentados anteriormente? Visto que o primeiro erro informa que existem NA's na base de dados, porém, ao observar a base de dados nenhum NA é observado, e mais, qual seria o motivo dessa segunda mensagem de erro estar aparecendo ao tentar ajustar o modelo acima?

Comment: Estou votando para fechar pois a pergunta não atende os critérios de um [mcve]. Leia [Como criar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/824/100416) - não há um conjunto de dados mínimo para a reprodução do problema. Dados sigilosos não devem ser publicados aqui, em casos assim, crie dados falsos ou mascare-os de modo que ainda seja possível reproduzir o problema.

Comment: @RafaelTavares os dados de acesso a links externos estão sendo removidos, inclusive do histórico (ficou muito mais complicado o processo por ter sido feito da maneira errada, com edits - gerou diversas entradas com os dados, em vez de sumir com elas). Nestes casos as perguntas devem ser fechadas de imediato. Nenhuma pergunta pode depender de links. E se perceber alguma com dados de acesso, sinalize para a moderação (usando o "outros problemas" que dá espaço para descrição textual).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema deve estar na forma como os dados são lidos do Google Drive. O ficheiro do link é um ficheiro CSV com vírgulas como marcador para as decimais. E o separador de colunas é o ponto-e-vírgula, `";"`. Para ler ficheiros neste formato CSV deve-se usar o `read.csv2`.

```
library(gamlss)

ModelGamlss <- gamlss(
  log(Var1) ~ re(fixed = ~ log(Var2) + log(Var3) + Var4 + Var5,
                 random = list(Var6 = pdDiag(~ Var7))),
  data = Data2)
#GAMLSS-RS iteration 1: Global Deviance = -1706.294 
#GAMLSS-RS iteration 2: Global Deviance = -1706.294 

summary(ModelGamlss)
#******************************************************************
#Family:  c("NO", "Normal") 
#
#Call:  gamlss(formula = log(Var1) ~ re(fixed = ~log(Var2) +  
#    log(Var3) + Var4 + Var5, random = list(Var6 = pdDiag(~Var7))),  
#    data = Data2) 
#
#Fitting method: RS() 
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------
#Mu link function:  identity
#Mu Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept) 3.100661   0.002601    1192   <2e-16 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------
#Sigma link function:  log
#Sigma Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept) -2.70187    0.02742  -98.53   <2e-16 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------
#NOTE: Additive smoothing terms exist in the formulas: 
# i) Std. Error for smoothers are for the linear effect only. 
#ii) Std. Error for the linear terms maybe are not accurate. 
#------------------------------------------------------------------
#No. of observations in the fit:  665 
#Degrees of Freedom for the fit:  49.27846
#      Residual Deg. of Freedom:  615.7215 
#                      at cycle:  2 
# 
#Global Deviance:     -1706.294 
#            AIC:     -1607.737 
#            SBC:     -1385.995 
#******************************************************************
```

### Leitura dos dados

De `help("read.csv2")`, ênfase minha:

> read.csv and read.csv2 are identical to read.table except for the defaults. They are intended for reading ‘comma separated value’ files (‘.csv’) or **(read.csv2) the variant used in countries that use a comma as decimal point and a semicolon as field separator**.

Tradução Google, editada:

> read.csv e read.csv2 são idênticos a read.table, exceto pelos padrões. Eles se destinam à leitura de arquivos de ‘valores separados por vírgula’ (‘.csv’) ou **(read.csv2) a variante usada em países que usam uma vírgula como ponto decimal e um ponto e vírgula como separador de campo.**

```
google_id <- "1q4XuSPnZXx7TsrT3JVoucFyxeOSegWFz"
google_file <- sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", google_id)
Data2 <- read.csv2(google_file)

str(Data2)
#'data.frame':  665 obs. of  7 variables:
# $ Var6: chr  "A5A" "A5A" "A5A" "A5A" ...
# $ Var2: num  15.8 15.8 15.8 15.8 15.8 15.8 15.8 15.8 15.8 15.8 ...
# $ Var1: num  15.1 10.9 13.2 13.5 16.8 15.4 16.1 15.2 15.3 13.9 ...
# $ Var3: num  0.817 1.512 1.267 1.262 0.754 ...
# $ Var4: num  0.0364 0.0674 0.0564 0.0562 0.0336 ...
# $ Var5: num  0.0801 0.1482 0.1242 0.1237 0.0739 ...
# $ Var7: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
```

Comment: Olá Rui! Muito obrigado pelo seu feedback. Então, estranho que mesmo eu usando o seguinte comando ````Data2 <- read.csv2("DataNew.csv", header=T, sep=";", dec=",")```` o erro ainda continua.

Comment: Rui, essa parte do seu código ````"https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download"```` você pegou onde?

Comment: @BrenoG. Não sei onde a encontrei, mas uso desde então e dá (quase?) sempre certo. O `id=%s` vai ter o valor `id=1q4XuSPnZXx7TsrT3JVoucFyxeOSegWFz`, veja `?sprintf`.

Comment: @BrenoG. Pode também fazer o download e depois `Data2 <- read.csv2("DataNew.csv")` chega, não são necessários os outros argumentos, porque já são esses os valores que têm. O `read.csv2` é uma forma deliberadamente inflexível de `read.table` com os argumentos apropriados.